# Showing Admob Ad for an app outside of Google Play

Tags: java, android, google-play, admob, ads

I have an android app and right now i want to publish it in google play and i want to monetize it with showing Google's Admob advertisement inside it.

I want to publish it inside another third party App stores. My question is that, if users that downloaded app from third party app stores clicks on banners, Admob sets them a legal click?

I just want that all of clicks from all app stores signs as correct clicks. I don't want miss any clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serving ads via AdMob is totally separate to Google Play.

You will still get served ads and will receive money for them even if your app is downloaded from another app store.

Comment: My PlayStore account was abruptly terminated for being associated with a previously terminated PlayStore account which I have no idea of,hence ad serving to the app on admob was disabled. Would creating a new ad Id for the same app on admob and uploading the app to a different app store(Amazon), would that be accepted?

Comment: I imagine so. As I said your Admob Id is totally separate to your PlayStore